# How to correct loop counters for maze algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, counter

I have figured out how to move my character around the maze using the algorithm I have written, but the count is not figuring correctly. At the end of each row my character moves up and down several times until the count reaches the specified number to exit the loop, then the character moves along the next row down until it reaches the other side and repeats the moving up and down until the count reaches the specified number again. Can anyone help me find why my count keeps getting off? The algorithm and the maze class I am calling from is listed below.

```
public class P4 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create maze
    String fileName = args[3];
    Maze maze = new Maze(fileName);
    System.out.println("Maze name: " + fileName);

    // Get dimensions
    int mazeWidth = maze.getWidth();
    int mazeHeight = maze.getHeight();

    // Print maze size
    System.out.println("Maze width: " + mazeWidth);
    System.out.println("Maze height: " + mazeHeight);

    int r = 0;
    int c = 0;

    // Move commands
    while (true){


        for (c = 0; c <= mazeWidth; c++){

            if (maze.moveRight()){
                maze.isDone();
                c++;
            }


            if (maze.isDone() == true){
                System.exit(1);
            }

            if (maze.moveRight() == false && c != mazeWidth){
                maze.moveDown();
                maze.moveRight();
                maze.moveRight();
                maze.moveUp();  
                c++;
            }
        }   
        for (r = 0; r % 2 == 0; r++){
            maze.moveDown();
            maze.isDone();

            if (maze.isDone() == true){
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
        for (c = mazeWidth; c >= 0; c--){
            if (maze.moveLeft()){
                c--;
                maze.isDone();
                System.out.println(c);
            }

            if (maze.isDone() == true){
                System.exit(1);
            }
            if (maze.moveLeft() == false && c != 0){
                maze.moveDown();
                maze.moveLeft();
                maze.moveLeft();
                maze.moveUp();
                c--;
            }   
        }
        for (r = 1; r % 2 != 0; r++){
            maze.moveDown();
            maze.isDone();

            if (maze.isDone() == true){
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

```
public class Maze {

// Maze variables
private char mazeData[][];
private int mazeHeight, mazeWidth;
private int finalRow, finalCol;
int currRow;
private int currCol;
private int prevRow = -1;
private int prevCol = -1;

// User interface
private JFrame frame;
private JPanel panel;
private Image java, student, success, donotpass;
private ArrayList<JButton> buttons;

// Maze constructor
public Maze(String fileName) {

    // Read maze
    readMaze(fileName);

    // Graphics setup
    setupGraphics();
}

// Get height
public int getHeight() {
    return mazeHeight;
}

// Get width
public int getWidth() {
    return mazeWidth;
}

// Move right
public boolean moveRight() {

    // Legal move?
    if (currCol + 1 < mazeWidth) {

        // Do not pass?
        if (mazeData[currRow][currCol + 1] != 'D') 
        {
            currCol++;
            redraw(true);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Move left
public boolean moveLeft() {

    // Legal move?
    if (currCol - 1 >= 0) {

        // Do not pass?
        if (mazeData[currRow][currCol - 1] != 'D') 
        {
            currCol--;
            redraw(true);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Move up
public boolean moveUp() {

    // Legal move?
    if (currRow - 1 >= 0) {

        // Do not pass?
        if (mazeData[currRow - 1][currCol] != 'D') 
        {
            currRow--;
            redraw(true);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Move down
public boolean moveDown() {

    // Legal move?
    if (currRow + 1 < mazeHeight) {

        // Do not pass?
        if (mazeData[currRow + 1][currCol] != 'D') 
        {
            currRow++;
            redraw(true);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean isDone() {

    // Maze solved?
    if ((currRow == finalRow) && (currCol == finalCol))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

private void redraw(boolean print) {

    // Wait for awhile
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }

    if (print)
        System.out.println("Moved to row " + currRow + ", column " + currCol);

    // Compute index and remove icon
    int index = (prevRow * mazeWidth) + prevCol;
    if ((prevRow >= 0) && (prevCol >= 0)) {
        buttons.get(index).setIcon(null);
    }

    // Compute index and add icon
    index = (currRow * mazeWidth) + currCol;
    if ((currRow == finalRow) && (currCol == finalCol))
        buttons.get(index).setIcon(new ImageIcon(success));
    else
        buttons.get(index).setIcon(new ImageIcon(student));

    // Store previous location
    prevRow = currRow;
    prevCol = currCol;
}

// Set button
private void setButton(JButton button, int row, int col) {

    if (mazeData[row][col] == 'S') {
        button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(student));
        currRow = row;
        currCol = col;
    } else if (mazeData[row][col] == 'J') {
        button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(java));
        finalRow = row;
        finalCol = col;
    } else if (mazeData[row][col] == 'D') {
        button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(donotpass));
    }
}

// Read maze
private void readMaze(String filename) {
    try {

        // Open file
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(filename));

        // Read numbers
        mazeHeight = scan.nextInt();
        mazeWidth = scan.nextInt();

        // Allocate maze
        mazeData = new char[mazeHeight][mazeWidth];

        // Read maze
        for (int row = 0; row < mazeHeight; row++) {

            // Read line
            String line = scan.next();
            for (int col = 0; col < mazeWidth; col++) {
                mazeData[row][col] = line.charAt(col);
            }
        }

        // Close file
        scan.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Cannot read maze: " + filename);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

// Setup graphics
private void setupGraphics() {

    // Create grid
    frame = new JFrame();
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(mazeHeight, mazeWidth, 0, 0));
    frame.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 5)), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // Look and feel
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Configure window
    frame.setSize(mazeWidth * 100, mazeHeight * 100);
    frame.setTitle("Maze");
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

    // Load and scale images
    ImageIcon icon0 = new ImageIcon("Java.jpg");
    Image image0 = icon0.getImage();
    java = image0.getScaledInstance(100, 100, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);

    ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon("Student.jpg");
    Image image1 = icon1.getImage();
    student = image1.getScaledInstance(100, 100, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);

    ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon("Success.jpg");
    Image image2 = icon2.getImage();
    success = image2.getScaledInstance(100, 100, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);

    ImageIcon icon3 = new ImageIcon("DoNotPass.jpg");
    Image image3 = icon3.getImage();
    donotpass = image3.getScaledInstance(100, 100, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);

    // Build panel of buttons
    buttons = new ArrayList<JButton>();

    for (int row = 0; row < mazeHeight; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < mazeWidth; col++) {

            // Initialize and add button
            JButton button = new JButton();
            Border border = new LineBorder(Color.darkGray, 4);
            button.setOpaque(true);
            button.setBackground(Color.gray);
            button.setBorder(border);
            setButton(button, row, col);
            panel.add(button);
            buttons.add(button);
        }
    }

    // Show window
    redraw(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: What exactly are you trying to count? The code you've posted is impossible to understand without knowing what the `Maze` class does, so I doubt you'll get any answers as this question is now. Please either explain with words what your algorithm is and the methods of that class do, or include the code. You should also probably add the `java` tag, in case it's some language feature you're tripping on (I don't see anything obvious, but I haven't written java in 10 years, so that doesn't mean too much).

Comment: I am counting the moves the character makes as it goes from one side of the maze to the other side. Once it reaches a certain count it is supposed to go down a row and go back across the maze. Which it does do eventually, but the character gets stuck at the end of each row until the count reaches a certain number. Either the mazeWidth on the right size or 0 on the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One error I can see in your code is that you're incrementing your `c` counter more often than you should. You start with it managed by your `for` loop, which means that it will be incremented (or decremented, for the leftward moving version) at the end of each pass through the loop. However, you also increment it an additional time in two of your `if` statements. That means that `c` might increase by two or three on a single pass through the loop, which is probably not what you intend.

Furthermore, the count doesn't necessarily have anything obvious to do with the number of moves you make. The loop code will always increase it by one, even if you're repeatedly trying to move through an impassible wall.

I don't really understand what your algorithm is supposed to be, so I don't have any detailed advice for how to fix your code.

One suggestion I have though is that you probably don't ever want to be calling methods on your `Maze` class without paying attention to their return values. You have a bunch of places where you call `isDone` but ignore the return value, which doesn't make any sense. Similarly, you should always be checking the return values from your `moveX` calls, to see if the move was successful or not. Otherwise you may just blunder around a bunch, without your code having any clue where you are in the maze.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advise. I will try implementing the changes you have suggested. Unfortunately, I have just about run out of time to do so, but your answer definitely has helped me figure out my errors.